# How can I use inline style with data attribute and browser prefix using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```js
$(".flex-container").css('justify-content', function(){
       $(this).css('justify-content',$(this).data("justify-content"));
    });
```

```css
.flex-container{
  display:flex;
  display:-webkit-flex;
  /**-webkit-justify-content: space-between; **/
  /** justify-content: space-between; **/
  -webkit-align-items: center;
  height:300px;
  width:400px;
  margin:0 auto;
  border:1px solid #d9d9d9;
}
.flex-item{
  width:100px;
  height:200px;
  border:1px solid #eee;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="flex-container" data-justify-content="space-between">
  <div class="flex-item">Flex Item one</div>
  <div class="flex-item">Flex Item two</div>
  <div class="flex-item">Flex Item three</div>
</div>
```

This code is good working but how can I add browser prefix (-webkit-justify-content: space-between; with justify-content: space-between;) using jquery

Answer (score 1):

You can use the jQuery `.css()` method

```
$('.flex-container').css({'-webkit-justify-content':'space-between',
                          'justify-content':'space-between'})
```

EDIT:

Based on your comments i think this is what you are looking for, basically you need to loop through all of the elements and assign it that way

```
$('.flex-container').each(function(){
    var justify = $(this).data('justify-content');
    $(this).css({'justify-content':justify,
                 '-webkit-justify-content':justify}})
})
```

Comment: Hi "CumminUp07" thanks for your ans. But I need to  "justify-content and -webkit-justify-content" in this method  Same as $(this).css('justify-content',$(this).data("justify-content")); using html5 data attribute follow my question jquery thanks

Comment: do you just need to add the browser prefix just like you added the `justify-content`?

Comment: I need to multiple flex-container to multiple value "$(this).data"
<div class="flex-container" data-justify-content="space-between">
  <div class="flex-item">Flex Item one</div>
</div>
<div class="flex-container" data-justify-content="flex-start">
  <div class="flex-item">Flex Item one</div>
</div>
<div class="flex-container" data-justify-content="flex-end">
  <div class="flex-item">Flex Item one</div>
</div>